# Created coded domain that didn't eliminate excluded entries

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, domains

While working on a geodatabase, I created a coded domain that was designed to restrict a "Sp_Code" (species code) field to an approved list of ~80 species. I loaded data I knew had bad species codes that shouldn't be accepted under the domain's rules. However, I still found those entries in the feature class after I loaded the data. I double checked to make sure the domain was acting on the correct field. Did I miss something? Was there a domain conflict management process I missed or still need to complete?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what a domain does. It will prevent you from entering values outside the domain using the attribute editor only after it is created and applied to a field but does not enforce the domain on the existing values. A user can still field calculate values that don't exist in the domain. You will need to find and resolve the existing values manually.

Comment: You can use your domain to validate a field after loading so search in the help for 'domain validate'.

Comment: Do you have a link for that tool @PolyGeo, the only links I can see are for PLTS/Production Mapping, Aviation, Defense Mapping etc.. all reviewer extensions. I do remember writing a tool to list all the unique values in a field and remove the entries that are valid for the domain then output a text file containing the 'bad' entries... I think it was 9.3 geoprocessor (or maybe even VB ArcObjects) though as I can't find it right now.

Comment: Thank you! I thought loading data in the domain would immediately catch the invalid entries. I just tried out the validation tool in the editor and have a much better understanding.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson without looking I think it is on the Editor toolbar pull down

Comment: Also from what I remember you need to go into edit mode, select all rows you want validate and only then does the option Validate Features on the editor toolbar enable.